# Use two or more Buttons to Show/hide and replace text in single DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building an about us page and I'm hoping to use JavaScript to show/hide/replace a DIV's content with a vision statement or a bio depending on which is clicked by the user. I'm brand new to using script, so I'm hoping there is someone who has done this before.

I currently have a button for the bio and one for the vision and while I'm able to show and hide text with no problem I have no clue how to replace the DIV so that the Bio and Vision don't show at the same time.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
 function showhide(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   e.style.display = (e.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
 }
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:showhide('vision')">Vision</button>
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:showhide('bio')">Bio</button>

<div id="vision" style="display: none;">
  <p>This is my vision</p>
</div>
<div id="bio" style="display: none;">
  <p>This is my bio</p>
</div>
```

I'd also like the button text to change to "Hide Bio" or "Hide Vision" depending on which is revealed as well.

If anyone could help with this it would be GREATLY appreciated for a Java Noob like me.

This is also my first time using a forum like this so any pointers or feedback is appreciated...gotta start somewhere, right?

[UPDATE - I attached an image to give a better idea of what I'm try to accomplish.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyaJu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with logic. If you show/hide one div, you'll still need to hide/show the second div. So you can either add more lines of code to do that.. or simply you can use one div and update its content based on the button clicked.

so you can try this:

```
<script>
var textStrings = {"author1": {"Vision":"this is author1 vision", "Bio":"this is author1 bio"},
                   "author2": {"Vision":"this is author2 vision", "Bio":"this is author2 bio"},
                   "author3": {"Vision":"this is author3 vision", "Bio":"this is author3 bio"}};
function showhide(element) {
  reset();
  var id=element.id;
  var author = document.getElementById("authors").elements["authors"].value;
  var flag = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML == textStrings[author][id];
  document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = flag ? "" : textStrings[author][id];
  element.innerHTML = flag ? id : "hide " + id;
}
function reset(){
  for (var k in textStrings["author1"]){
    document.getElementById(k).innerHTML = k;
  }
 }

function resetAuthor(){
  document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = ""
  reset();
}

</script>

<form id="authors">
 <input type="radio" name="authors" id="author1" onchange="resetAuthor()" value="author1" checked> author 1
 <input type="radio" name="authors" id="author2" onchange="resetAuthor()" value="author2"> author 2
 <input type="radio" name="authors" id="author3" onchange="resetAuthor()" value="author3"> author 3
</form>

<div style="display:inline">
<button type="button" id="Vision" onclick="javascript:showhide(this)">Vision</button>
<button type="button" id="Bio" onclick="javascript:showhide(this)">Bio</button>
</div>
<div style="display: block;">
  <p id="content"></p>
</div>
```

This code also toggles/set contents as empty if you hit the button again.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/jdcxxd8m/2/)

Comment: This works pretty well. My only concern is if I wanted to add more authors. There could be up to three BIO's and Visions when the site actually goes live.

Comment: can be an easy extension, you could use three 'textStrings' variables having details of each of the author and use a different variable depending upon which author to highlight. Or you could use one variable and have all authors in it their names as keys and bio/vision details as values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Would you be able to show me one of these option in action with one additional author in the mix? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks again! I added an image to my original post for you to understand that the radio buttons wont work in this case although I found it to be a very clever solution.

Comment: yea... so you've got 6 buttons... you can tag each of them with the desired place in the json data. No authors radio button required.

Comment: and please mark and close the question whenever u done. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the `this` object into the inline event handler and check the content's `display` state to `toggle` the button's text,

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:showhide('vision',this)">Vision</button>
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:showhide('bio',this)">Bio</button>

<div id="vision" style="display: none;">
  <p>This is my vision</p>
</div>
<div id="bio" style="display: none;">
  <p>This is my bio</p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function showhide(id,elem) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   var cond = (e.style.display == 'block');
   e.style.display = cond ? 'none' : 'block';
   elem.textContent = (id == "vision") ? (cond ? "Show Vision" : "Hide Vision") 
                                    : (cond ? "Show Bio" : "Hide Bio");

}
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ratzr2j3/)

Comment: Thanks for you quick response! This definitely helps with adding "Hide" to the buttons after they are toggled but I'm still not able to replace the text depending on which button is clicked. If you click vision first and bio second it shows both at the same time. I'd like them to replace each other depending on which is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```js
var prevPage = "";
var currPage = "";

function showhide(event) {
  prevPage = currPage;
  currPage = event.id.split("_")[1];
  if(prevPage !== currPage){
    showEle(currPage);
    if(prevPage !== ''){
     hideEle(prevPage);
    }
  } else {
    toggle(currPage);
  }
}

function toggle(id){
  var curr = document.getElementById(id);
  if(curr.style.display === 'block'){
    curr.style.display = 'none';
    updateBtn('btn_'+id, 'Show');
  } else {
    curr.style.display = 'block';
    updateBtn('btn_'+id, 'Hide');
  }
  
}

function updateBtn(id, newStr){
  var btn = document.getElementById(id);
  btn.innerHTML = newStr + ' ' + btn.innerHTML.split(' ')[1];
}

function showEle(id){
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
  updateBtn('btn_'+id, 'Hide');
}

function hideEle(id){
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
  updateBtn('btn_'+id, 'Show');
}
```

```html
<button id="btn_vision" type="button" onclick="showhide(this)">Show Vision</button>
<button id="btn_bio" type="button" onclick="showhide(this)">Show Bio</button>
<button id="btn_xyz" type="button" onclick="showhide(this)">Show Xyz</button>
<button id="btn_abc" type="button" onclick="showhide(this)">Show Abc</button>

<div id="vision" style="display: none;">
  <p>This is my vision</p>
</div>
<div id="bio" style="display: none;">
  <p>This is my bio</p>
</div>
<div id="xyz" style="display: none;">
  <p>This is my xyz</p>
</div>
<div id="abc" style="display: none;">
  <p>This is my abc</p>
</div>
```

Note: You might want to initialize the currPage with the first page's id since it gives a better feel.
Say currPage = "vision" and also make display block for div id = "vision".

Comment: Thanks for your help! This doesn't seem to allow you to toggle the text off and I'd also like the button text to change to "Hide Bio" or "Hide Vision" depending on which is revealed.

Comment: Edited the code. Its always better to have a separator in the button's id eg. btn_bio, which you can split and get the actual id of the page you want to show or hide.